# While upgrading the axis2, i got the foolowing java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined 'Security policy namespace cannot be null.' resource property

Tags: web-services, osgi, apache-axis, rampart, jetty-8

I am getting the following exception while upgrading the axis2 version from 1.5.4 to 1.6.1.Note i am using OSGi 3.8.2,jetty server version 8.1.3

2015-09-04 19:21:42.250:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/services/WebServiceReceiver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined 'Security policy namespace cannot be null.' resource property
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartException.getMessage(RampartException.java:81)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartException.(RampartException.java:41)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartException.(RampartException.java:57)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.setWSSecurityVersions(RampartMessageData.java:373)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartMessageData.(RampartMessageData.java:261)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:61)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:516)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:216)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:851)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2015-09-04 19:21:42,292] 637744 [Thread-95] ERROR errors  - ERROR:CONNECTOR:webserviceconnector:Attempted read on closed stream.
[2015-09-04 19:21:42,294] 637746 [Thread-95] ERROR errors  - CONNECTOR:webserviceconnector:webservice:Attempted read on closed stream.